# Conditional Rendering for react-router Link attributes

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, conditional-statements, rendering, react-router

I'm trying to disable certain attributes for Link in my React project. The buttons display on multiple pages, so I need them to conditionally render.

Here's an example of a Cancel button and Refund button, with disableCancelButton and disableRefundButton being booleans that look at various factors to determine if the button should show. My attempt:

```
<Link {{disableRefundButton} && to={"/rentals/" + rentalId + "/refund"}}>Refund</Link>

<Link {{disableCancelButton} && onClick={this.props.onCancel}}>Cancel</Link>
```

I also tried:

```
<Link {{disableRefundButton} ? to={"/rentals/" + rentalId + "/refund"}}>Refund</Link>
```

I'm sure I'm off with a curly brace somewhere. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Here's another failed attempt... lol
    <Link onClick={{disableCancelButton} ? e.preventDefault : this.props.onClose}}>Cancel</Link>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to conditionally render the whole component, not just the props?

```
{!disableRefundButton &&
  <Link to={"/rentals/" + rentalId + "/refund"}}>Refund</Link>}

{!disableCancelButton &&
  <Link onClick={this.props.onCancel}}>Cancel</Link>}
```

Comment: I want the button to stay there. It's part of the design as the product goes through the different stages of its process: Check In, Check Out, Cancel, Close. Most of our buttons just fade to disabled, not vanish.

Comment: So I need the Link to stay, and just the attribute onClick attribute to null.